# Laravel get soft deleted records in query

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, php-7.4

I'm using Laravel 8 with php 7.4

User model:

```
class User extends Model {
    use SoftDeletes;

    public function getList($search, $trashed)
    {
        $query = User::select('*');
        if (!is_null($search)) {
            $query->where('name', 'LIKE', $search);
        }
        if ($trashed) {
            $query->withTrashed();
        }
        dd($query->toSql()); // return "select * from users where deleted_at is null;"
        dd(User::select('*')->withTrashed()); // return "select * from users;"
        return $query->get();
    }
}
```

How do I use withTrashed() with a condition? Do I have to write a separate function like addTrashed($query) and return $query->withTrashed() and then use addTrashed($query)->get();

Comment: are you sure you are passing boolean value to getList() second param.can you show how you are accessing getList method

Comment: are you sure ``$trashed`` is set to true?

Comment: Yes the $trashed param was true. I did put a dd in the if bracket to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel scope for this

```
public function getList($search, $trashed)
    {
        $users= User::select('*')->Search($search)->Wtrahed($trashed)->get();
       return $users;
    }


public function scopeWtrashed($query, $trashed)
    {
     
        if ($trashed) {
          return  $query->withTrashed();
        }
     
    }


public function scopeSearch($query, $search)
    {
     
        if (isset($search) && !empty($search)) {
          return  $query->where('name', 'LIKE', $search);
        }
     
    }
```

Comment: Is Using scope the only way? I'm more curious about how withTrashed() doesn't work. Or is it not the intended way to use it?